# How to get cloud function onCreate trigger doc id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the id of the document that trigger the oncreate function but i tried `snap.params.id` like below but i am getting undefined.

When i console log this `projectId`, i am getting undefined and sometimes throws error and i am using version "firebase-admin": "~5.12.1", "firebase-functions": "^1.0.3"

```js
exports.created = functions.firestore.document('projects/{projectId}')
.onCreate(snap => {

  const projectId = snap.params.id;

  const project = snap.data();
  const notification = {
    title: `${project.title}`,
    projectId: `${projectId}`
  }

});
```

So how do i get the document id?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since you use a Cloud Functions version >= 1.0, events for `onCreate` have two parameters as shown below, and you should use `context.params`.

```js
exports.created = functions.firestore.document('projects/{projectId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const projectId = context.params.projectId;

    const project = snap.data();

    //......

});
```

See this doc [item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) for more detail.

Comment: it worked but asking for package upgrade which i am certain will fail because i upgraded before and was having issues so i downgraded.

Comment: I don't think you should be afraid to upgrade. You are using quite an old version of firebase-functions, see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases