# Firebase cloud functions: How to get the reference to the document with wildcard notation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Here are what I am trying to do with Firebase cloud functions:

1. Listen to change in one of the documents under 'public_posts' collection.
2. Tell if the change is in the 'public' field from true to false
3. If true, delete the document that triggered the function

For steps 1&2, the code is straightforward, but I don't know the syntax for step 3. What would be the way to get the reference of the document that triggered the function? That is, I'd like to know what would be the code in question for the empty line below:

```
exports.checkPrivate = functions.firestore
.document('public_posts/{postid}').onUpdate((change,context)=>{
     const data=change.after.data();
     if (data.public===false){
         //get the reference of the trigger document and delete it 
     }
     else {
         return null;
     }
});
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore):

> For `onWrite` and `onUpdate` events, the `change` parameter has before and
> after fields. Each of these is a `DataSnapshot`.

So, you can do as follows:

```
exports.checkPrivate = functions.firestore
.document('public_posts/{postid}').onUpdate((change, context)=>{
     const data=change.after.data();
     if (!data.public) { //Note the additional change here
 
         const docRef = change.after.ref;
         return docRef.delete();

     }
     else {
         return null;
     }
});
```

---

**Update following Karolina Hagegård comment below:**
If you want to get the value of the `postid` wildcard, you need to use the `context` object like: `context.params.postid`.

Strictly speaking you get the document id, not its `DocumentReference`. Of course, based on this value, you can rebuild the `DocumentReference` with `` admin.firestore().doc(`public_posts/${postid}`); `` which will give the same object than `change.after.ref`.

Comment: That's great, but surely there must also be a way to use this "postid" thing from the wild card notation...? Why else would you give it a name there... 

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Sure, you can use the `context` object, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815202/3371862).

Comment: Aaaaaaah, nice! :) I like that.

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård you may upvote the other answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The onUpdate listener returns a `Change` object (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change)

To get the updated document you would do:

`change.after.val()`

To remove the document you would do:

`change.after.ref.remove()`

Comment: You haven't declared "change"... I'm guessing you've named your response from the `onUpdate` that, but since it's possible to name it anything, it's nice if you explicitly say so. :)